# Deploy .net applicaton with SQL Server

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment

I've done my windows form application and it connects to a SQL Server database using Linq-to-SQL.

But to put it on my client, is one hell ...

I do not think I do rather like to configure my connection string dynamically inform him picking up my client.

Anyone have any ideas?
Documents, tutorials, anything.

Thank you.

Comment: try taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143448/connection-string-security-in-net-desktop-application)

Answer (score 1):

You're question is not clear to me, but I can make a couple interpretations.

The first is that you're trying to deploy Sql Server to each workstation.  Sql Server, even Express Edition, is not intended to be deployed to individual workstations.  This is a *supported* configuration and it is *possible*, but it is not at all *recommended*.  If this is what you want to do, you are much better off using Sql Server *Compact* Edition, Sqlite, or even Access.

The second is that there will be a central server for each organization using your product, but you are not sure how to distribute the connection information for that server.  Here, the best option is a custom installer action that asks for and sets the connection string in your app config file. Administrator at each organization can then at their option create an answer file for your installer that supplies the needed information automatically.

Comment: would be the second option, I can not set the connection string to get data from the bank that the installer just created

Comment: @Fernando - if it's the second option, why did the installer "just create" a database?  If it did, you didn't listen hard enough to the first option: don't deploy sql server databases to each client. Don't do it.

Comment: yes, the server would be alone, but the problem is to identify the connection string