# How to securely store strings in a desktop Windows Forms app

Tags: c++, security, connection-string

I'm developing a Windows Forms app (C++) in order to collect data (and other functionalities) from machines which are installed in customers' warehouses. The app displays the information that is been gathered in runtime and stores it in our cloud database.

In order to access the database I need to store the connection string (and other passwords such as email passwords to send e-mails from the app) somewhere and I'm not sure which is the best way to accomplish this, eventhough I'm aware that there's no completely secure way to do that.

For additional information:

- C++ is the chosen language since one of the core functionalities of the app relies on a C++ library for the PC to machine connection.
- The system where the app is running is in the customer's warehouse.
- The customer has a windows user in order to run the app, same user we use to connect remotely.
- More users can be created in the machine (with more privileges, so only us can access said user), which can be useful for the [solution nº 1 proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143448/connection-string-security-in-net-desktop-application). Eventhough I've never heard of WCF windows service and I don't know where to start in order to implement that solution.
- All customers use the same app which connects to the same database.

How could I store the passwords so they can't be easily compromised? What is the common solution in cases like this?

Comment: If all you want is to prevent the user from directly connect to the database, just use a webservice on the server, make it connect to the DB and block the DB in the firewall. WCF or not, it'll isolate those credentials from the user.

Comment: So should I write my own API to post/get data? But then I would need some credentials in order to acces the webservice. Sorry for the obvious questions but I'm not that experienced in the field.

Comment: Sure, but you ask the user for them in a login, then the webservice knows who you are and can go to the DB and the required resources. This is pretty much the very same way you (indirectly) use the Stack Overflow database :D

Comment: Wouldn't that allow the user to modify the database using http requests? At which point is the security enforced?

Comment: Yes, it will. That's why you ask for a password in a login screen beforehand, then use that access to authenticate all further requests. Security is enforced in that webservice, which will check for valid credential/access token/whatever, and furthermore, which permissions have that user. Invalid or unauthenticated requests will be rejected and the DB untouched. The DB or any other system behind the server, won't be accessed if the server denies the request.